# Problem solving differential equations using odeint and sympy

Tags: python, math, sympy, odeint

I am trying to solve and display a graph of the following equation:

> f'=a*f²-b*f

Therefore I have tried to use `scipy.integrate.odeint` library function to solve it without success.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
from IPython.display import display
import sympy as sy
from sympy.solvers.ode import dsolve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sympy import functions
from sympy import Function, Symbol

sy.init_printing()

t = sy.symbols("t", real=True)
f = sy.symbols("f", cls=functions)

eq1 = sy.Eq(f(t).diff(t), (0.1*f(t)**2 - 2*f(t)))
sls = dsolve(eq1)

print("For ode")
display(eq1)
print("the solutions are:")
for s in sls:
    display(s)

# plot solutions:
x = np.linspace(0, 3, 100)
fg, axx = plt.subplots(5000, 3)
```

Then I would like to display it for different *f₀* (condition at *t=0*) as you would do for a normal equation which would look like this:

[image: graph]

Comment: Are there any initial conditions or anything else to limit the solutions to only one? If not, what kind of graph do you want to display? (Your last paragraph is not clear: a "normal equation" is just one equation.) Just what is wrong with the code you show?

Comment: @RoryDaulton i added some example concerning the output. Concerning the input it is the eqaution solving which is not working as i get errors concerning the declaration of the function

Comment: If you want to use `odeint`, please take into account that you have to provide actual values for the symbols `a` and `b`

Comment: @gboffi :   I did set a and b: a is 0.1 and 2 as you can read in my code (0.1*f(t)**2 - 2*f(t))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved your problem using Sympy with the `isympy` shell (that ease a little defining names, etc) — you have to be more careful to do all the necessary `import`s.

1. I solved the differential equation, took the *rhs* (right hand side) of the resulting equation and assigned said *rhs* expression to the variable `sol`.
2. I solved for `c1` the equation `f(0)-x0=0`.
3. I assigned (arbitrarily) values to the different symbols involved.
4. I plotted the function after substituting actual values for all the variables except for `t`, the free variable of our plot.
   [image]

```
18:43 boffi@debian:~ $ isympy 
IPython console for SymPy 1.4 (Python 3.7.4-64-bit) (ground types: gmpy)

These commands were executed:
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
>>> k, m, n = symbols('k m n', integer=True)
>>> f, g, h = symbols('f g h', cls=Function)
>>> init_printing()

Documentation can be found at https://docs.sympy.org/1.4/


In [1]: a, b = symbols('a b')                                                             

In [2]: sol = dsolve(Derivative(f(t), t) + a*f(t)**2 + b*f(t), f(t)).rhs                  

In [3]: c1, x0 = symbols('C1 x0')                                                         

In [4]: c1_from_x0, = solve(sol.subs(t, 0) - x0, c1)                                      

In [5]: sol, c1_from_x0, sol.subs(c1, c1_from_x0)                                         
Out[5]: 
⎛                       ⎛  a⋅x₀  ⎞                                ⎞
⎜        C₁⋅b        log⎜────────⎟                                ⎟
⎜     b⋅ℯ               ⎝a⋅x₀ + b⎠               b⋅x₀             ⎟
⎜──────────────────, ─────────────,  ──────────────────────────────⎟
⎜  ⎛   C₁⋅b    b⋅t⎞        b                   ⎛    a⋅x₀      b⋅t⎞⎟
⎜a⋅⎝- ℯ     + ℯ   ⎠                 (a⋅x₀ + b)⋅⎜- ──────── + ℯ   ⎟⎟
⎝                                              ⎝  a⋅x₀ + b       ⎠⎠

In [6]: values = {x0:10, a:3, b:4, c1:c1_from_x0}                                         

In [7]: plot(sol.subs(values), (t, 0, 0.5));

In [8]: sol.subs(values).simplify()                                                      
Out[8]: 
     20     
────────────
    4⋅t     
17⋅ℯ    - 15

In [9]:
```

---

***Addendum***

For completeness, the numerical solution using `scipy.integrate.odeint` <sup>1</sup>

```
from numpy import exp, linspace 
from scipy.integrate import odeint 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
 
t = linspace(0, 0.5, 201) ; f0 = 10; a = 3 ; b = 4                                
f = odeint(lambda f, t: (-a*f -b)*f, f0, t)                                       

fig0, ax0 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,3))                                           
ax0.plot(t, f) ; ax0.set_title('Numerical Solution')
plt.show()

exact = 20 / (17*exp(4*t)-15)                                                     
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,3))                                           
ax1.plot(t, (f.flat-exact)*1E6) ; ax1.set_title('(Numerical-Analytical)*10**6')   
plt.show()
```

[image: Numerical Solution]

[image: Error plot]

<sup>1. For new code, use `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` to solve a differential equation.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It always helps to know the closed-form solution if you can get it.  I asked Wolfram Alpha to solve your ODE.  [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%27%20%3D%20a*f%5E2%20-%20b*f) is the answer they gave me.

I'd recommend plotting that so you'll know the right answer when you see it.